# htaccess password protecting single file. I still get password prompt on other files

Tags: apache, file, .htaccess, permissions, directory

Below is my htaccess file. 2 things are happening here. In the first part of the code I make sure server is in https. In the second part filesmatch I want to password protect one file. This works as it should. However, I do not want other files in the directory to be prompt the user for a password. When I attempt to access another page say index.php I still get a password prompt. If I click cancel I am allowed access to the file as I should be, but how do I get it to not prompt for the other files at all?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} reservations 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/reservations/$1 [R,L]

<filesMatch "protectme.php">
  AuthName "Username and password required"
  AuthUserFile "/home/path/.htpasswds/passwd"
  Require valid-user
  AuthType Basic
</filesMatch>
```